# Модель с именем Event в Laravel

Tags: laravel, namespace

У меня есть модель, которая назвается Event:

```
class Event extends Eloquent {
    // ...
}
```

Внутри неё содержатся правила и сообщения для валидатора, поэтому, чтобы проверить данные в контролере, я делаю вот так:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Event::$rules, Event::$messages);
```

В результате чего у меня возникает ошибка:

> *Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::$rules*

Я понимаю, что это из-за того, что в Laravel уже используется класс Event и что именно в нем он пытается найти переменную $rules.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы можно было использовать модель с именем Event?

*Конечно, можно назвать модель myEvent, но это как-то некрасиво.*

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите модели в пространство имён.

```
// composer.json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Models\\": "app/models",
        }
    }
}
```

Обновите автозагрузчик: `composer dump-autoload -o`

Модели:

```
// app/models/Event.php
<?php

namespace Models; // думаю, сами знаете как это делается

class Event extends \Eloquent {}
```

Не забудьте о настройках авторизации (и других..):

```
// app/config/auth.php
<?php

return [
    'model' => 'Models\User',
];
```

*Да, похоже, легче переименовать модель, но это же может быть не последнее совпадение.*

Comment: Ясно спасибо, я тогда лучше переименую модель. Потому что пока что не очень хорошо понимаю psr-4

Comment: Дело ваше, хотя не так страшен чёрт, как его малюют. Да и сам ``psr-4`` - ерунда, за вас там всё сделает автозагрузчик.  
А вот пространства имён.. мне понравилась эта статейка: [PHP Namespaces Explained](http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained)